# Creating a dynamic GUI using wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to create a dynamic GUI using wxPython. My aim is to constantly read values of voltage and current and refresh the window so that they're constantly updated. There can be or not be a delay between the reading of values. My code till now is as follows:

```
    import wx
    import time as sleep

    class windowClass(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            super(windowClass, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200, 71))
            self.Centre()
            self.Show()
            self.basicGUI()

        def basicGUI(self):


   V = input('Enter V: ')
        C = input('Enter C: ') 
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        Voltage = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Voltage: ", (3, 3))
        Current = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Current: ", (3, 23))
        vValue = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, str(V), (70, 3))
        cValue = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, str(C), (70, 23))

    app = wx.App()
    windowClass(None, title = 'Output Window')
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm new to this and don't know how to proceed from here. My aim is to print new values and delete the old values(frames). Thanks!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? How can I make this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For att change wx.StaticText label you can use SetLabel.

For att call vValue and cValue from another def in same Class you should rename them to self.vValue and self.cValue.

```
def basicGUI(self):
    V = input('Enter V: ')
    C = input('Enter C: ') 
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.Voltage = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Voltage: ", (3, 3))
    self.Current = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Current: ", (3, 23))
    self.vValue = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, str(V), (70, 3))
    self.cValue = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, str(C), (70, 23))

    #delete inputed values and set new ex. 66,77
    self.update(66,77)

def update(self,V,C):
    self.vValue.SetLabel(str(V))
    self.cValue.SetLabel(str(C))
```

Setlabel values should be str.

Comment: Thanks! Although I did find what worked for me on a different answer, it was really similar to this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe his is good idea to add link in comment to solution you found to help other user or accept this answer.